# Overhanding properties when rendering Asciidoctor documents with Maven Site plugin

Tags: maven-site-plugin, asciidoctor

My Maven site contains serveral Asciidoctor documents. I would like to use the properites declared in the configuration of the Maven Site plugin, but it seems so that they are not overhanded to Asciidoctor.

```xml
<plugin> 
  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId> 
  <dependencies>         
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>             
      <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>                  
    </dependency>                        
  </dependencies>     
  <configuration>         
    <attributes> 
      <ta>ddd</ta> 
    </attributes>     
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is an example how I try to use the attribute `ta` in my Asciidoctor documents.

```
= Example Document

Value of ta is: {ta}
```

How can I use the attributes defined for Maven Site plugin in my Asciidoctor documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment (as of AsciidoctorJ 1.52) it is not possible to use the attributes of Maven Site in Asciidoctor documents.

I filed an issue on this (https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/issues/170).

For the time being I found a workarount. I use the resouces plugin to write all properties to a file and include this file in my documents. A workaround. A direkt access to defined attributes would be more convenient.